# "Nice" html table using SQL results

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I currently have this html table using SQL results to fill it:

```
<table> 
<table border="1">
    <tr> 

        <th>Username</th> 
        <th>holid</th> 
        <th>Start date</th> 
        <th>end date</th> 
        <th>Work days off</th> 


    </tr> 
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['starthol'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['endhol'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['days'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><a href="#">Approve</a></td> 
            <td><a href="#">Reject</a></td> 

        </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

This works fine and everything, but the table is very messy and the headings are out of line. Is there a simple way to make this cleaner (php beginner).

Comment: The question sends the signal tha you are an HTML beginner too. I'd start by reading some tutorials regarding that. For this purpose, you should not create a separate table for each row read from DB, just the `<tr>`'s, and what is inside them...

Comment: You are creating a lot of <table>'s, you should check what HTML is rendered after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the extra table tag removed coding and see below for the css coding.

```
<table border="1">
<tr> 

    <th>Username</th> 
    <th>holid</th> 
    <th>Start date</th> 
    <th>end date</th> 
    <th>Work days off</th> 


</tr> 
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 

    <tr> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['starthol'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['endhol'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['days'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
        <td><a href="#">Approve</a></td> 
        <td><a href="#">Reject</a></td> 

    </tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</table> 


/*css styles*/

table { 

    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
    background: #eee; 
}
th { 
    background: #333; 
    color: white; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
    padding: 6px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
}
```

Comment: thank you, I understand now. It was the loop that was throwing me :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the second `<table border="1">`, the one below the `foreach` instruction.

**EDIT**: And one of the first ones as well. Every `<table>` tag should have one corresponding `</table>` (that goes for all tags in `HTML`!)

Also, try to match `<th>`s with `<td>`s. Right now there are 5 `<th>`s and each row has 6 `<td>`s.